# Batch file command to copy files from one location/directory to another location based on condition

Tags: batch-file

**Scenario:**

I want to copy the particular file to another locaton.

**Destination folder path: `D:\Correct\email`**

**Source folder path: `C:\Revert\email`.**

Here in `email` folder there will be many subfolders and each subfolder contains exactly two files like `abc.csv` and `xyz.csv`
so I want to copy the file `abc.csv` from the latest created folder(ie in the subfolders of email folder) to destination folder and need not to know the name of subfolder.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a sorted list of directories with

```
dir /B /TC /O-D /AD
```

You can get the first result into a variable with

```
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%D in (`dir /B /TC /O-D /AD C:\Revert\email`) do if not defined Newest set Newest=%%~fD
```

You can then copy the files with

```
copy /Y %Newest%\*.csv D:\Correct\email
```